# wakeup a kernel thread that is in sleep using msleep

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have created and started a kernel thread using "kthread_run". 
    task1 = kthread_run(flash, NULL, "LED_thread");
I have to basically blink an LED in 4 different patterns with different on off times. I am using "msleep" for this. For example if in a pattern, the off time is 10 seconds, i switch off the led and then use a "msleep(10000)". Now the problem is if the pattern is changed from user space, the pattern changes only after this delay of 10seconds is completed.

In order to solve i have started a second thread which monitors the pattern of the LED and as soon as it sees a change in the pattern, it tries to wakeup the first thread using "wake_up_process(task1)"

But this doesnot wake up the first thread.

So my question is does:
1. wake_up_process wakeup a thread in sleep (sheduled away from run queue)?
2. if it doesnot, is there any other of acccomplishing this.

Thanks in advance
Srik

In my "flash" thread function, i have

**UPDATE:**

**@Craig**, its a nice example you gave to implement the whole thing in a single thread. In my opinion threads hog a lot of cpu cycles, so it is better to have as less threads as possible. Do you agree on that?
Alternative besides your example of avoiding the other thread is:
1. to use ioctl in the driver and to set the mode from user space using this ioctl instead of the sysfs attribute i was using and send the signal to the worker thread to wake it up, when the ioctl command is received.
2. send the signal to wake up the worker thread in the store function of the mode sysfs attribute (function in the driver which will be called when the mode is set in user space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `msleep_interruptible` instead of `msleep` in thread A. Dunno for sure, but you may have to have thread B do the wakeup by sending a signal instead of `wake_up_process`. Try both and see.

You may need some interlock (e.g. spinlock) to prevent a race condition where thread B sends the signal after thread A has already woken up [and has already seen the blink type change].

Or, thread A could remember the old type and just continue with the remaining sleep if there was no change (this compensates for a race without the need to lock)

---

Here's the kernel code for each:

```
/**
 * msleep - sleep safely even with waitqueue interruptions
 * @msecs: Time in milliseconds to sleep for
 */
void msleep(unsigned int msecs)
{
    unsigned long timeout = msecs_to_jiffies(msecs) + 1;

    while (timeout)
        timeout = schedule_timeout_uninterruptible(timeout);
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(msleep);

/**
 * msleep_interruptible - sleep waiting for signals
 * @msecs: Time in milliseconds to sleep for
 */
unsigned long msleep_interruptible(unsigned int msecs)
{
    unsigned long timeout = msecs_to_jiffies(msecs) + 1;

    while (timeout && !signal_pending(current))
        timeout = schedule_timeout_interruptible(timeout);
    return jiffies_to_msecs(timeout);
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(msleep_interruptible);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks for pointing to the possible race condition as well. I will try with semaphores/mutexes and see

It's probably not necessary if thread B does the monitoring (e.g. reading `/dev/whatever` or `/proc/whatever`) and writes a global [possibly inside the "private" data struct]. You might have to use an *atomic* fetch/store or CAS, but marking it `volatile` might be sufficient. This is because B is the [only] writer and A is the [only] reader.

> As far as sending signals in kernel space, can we do that? i thought signals are only for userspace. Could you give me an example if that is not the case.

Since `msleep_interruptible` exists at *all*, and it looks for pending signals, that's QED right there.

But, here's some code that proves it. The comment in `allow_signal` has been around since a patch from 2003:

```
/*
 * Let kernel threads use this to say that they allow a certain signal.
 * Must not be used if kthread was cloned with CLONE_SIGHAND.
 */
int allow_signal(int sig)
{
    if (!valid_signal(sig) || sig < 1)
        return -EINVAL;

    spin_lock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
    /* This is only needed for daemonize()'ed kthreads */
    sigdelset(&current->blocked, sig);
    /*
     * Kernel threads handle their own signals. Let the signal code
     * know it'll be handled, so that they don't get converted to
     * SIGKILL or just silently dropped.
     */
    current->sighand->action[(sig)-1].sa.sa_handler = (void __user *)2;
    recalc_sigpending();
    spin_unlock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
    return 0;
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(allow_signal);

int disallow_signal(int sig)
{
    if (!valid_signal(sig) || sig < 1)
        return -EINVAL;

    spin_lock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
    current->sighand->action[(sig)-1].sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    recalc_sigpending();
    spin_unlock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
    return 0;
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(disallow_signal);
```

Just use the internal call. That's probably `do_send_sig_info`. Use something innocuous like `SIGUSR1` (or you may need to use an "RT" signal because they are queued).

Sending a signal, in the kernel, means that the signal is OR'ed into the task's pending signal mask, and the task is marked runnable (e.g. gets woken up).

The userspace "jump to handler" occurs *only* when a given task is about to reenter [the last thing before reentering] userspace. If a signal is set, the kernel sets up the userspace stack frame and switches execution to the handler.

In a kernel thread, it does *not* cause a jump to a "signal handler" as there isn't an equivalent. The kernel thread must look at its pending signal mask to notice it at all. There is *no* jump. It is *not* like an interrupt. And, the kernel thread must manually clear the pending mask [otherwise, `msleep_interruptible` will thereafter *always* return immediately].

To detect and clear a signal, here's some code:

```
while (signal_pending(current)) {
    siginfo_t info;
    unsigned long signo;

    signo = dequeue_signal_lock(current, &current->blocked, &info));

    switch (signo) {
    case SIGUSR1:
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> The msleep_interruptible was not wakeable using `wake_up_process`, but only with `send_sig_info`. I think `msleep_interruptible` is nothing but : `setstate(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE)` and `schedule()` with delay, so i had expected `wake_up_process` to wakeup the thread sleeping with `msleep_interruptible`.

[AFAIK] You have to send a signal to terminate the sleep early, hence my original comment about using a signal (and using `do_send_sig_info`). Sometimes it's just trial and error. I might have tried `wake_up_process`, too. But, when that didn't work, I'd start looking around [by looking at the `msleep*` code].

> But neverthless it would be interesting to understand if it is possible to implement that in a single thread.

Yes. It requires a small bit of restructuring and an extra variable or two.

> My blink thread should set LED on for a second

Let's call this `blink_interval_on`

> and depending on the mode it is in, has to set LED off after the 1 second for about 10 seconds or 1 second.

Let's call this `blink_interval_off`

> If we implement it in a single thread, polling will be delayed by those 10 seconds right?

The key change [conceptually] is that the value given to `msleep` needn't be the *entire* interval (e.g. `blink_interval_*`) but can be a smaller *fixed* interval. Let's call this `sleep_fixed`.

We want to choose this to provide the responsiveness that you'd like. If it's *very* small (e.g. one microsecond), we'd be waking up too often. If we choose a *large* value like 1 second or 10 seconds, the response becomes "sluggish".

So, a good value would be 10-100 milliseconds. Slow enough that we're not hogging resources by frequent wakeups, but fast enough that a user won't notice the difference if the blink mode changes.

Now, we have to keep track of how much time is remaining for a given blink interval [bumping down by `sleep_fixed`], and flip the LED state when the interval becomes exhausted.  That is, we manually keep track of what the full `msleep` used to do for us.

> Can you give me an example for that.

Okay, here's a crude/pseudo-code version to [hopefully] explain what I mean:

```
// NOTE: all times are in milliseconds

int blink_interval_on;                  // LED "on" interval
int blink_interval_off;                 // LED "off" interval

int blink_interval_remaining;           // time remaining in current interval
int curmode;                            // current blink mode

int blink_on_list[2] = { 1000, 1000 };
int blink_off_list[2] = { 1000, 10000 };

int sleep_fixed;                        // small sleep value

// set_led_on -- set LED on or off
void
set_led_on(int onflg)
{
}

// msleep -- sleep for specified number of milliseconds
void
msleep(int ms)
{
}

// getnewmode -- get desired blink mode
// RETURNS: 0=1 second, 1=10 seconds, etc (-1=stop)
int
getnewmode(void)
{
    int newmode;

    // do whatever is necessary, as you're doing now ...
    newmode = 0;

    return newmode;
}

// ledloop -- main thread for single thread case
void
ledloop(void)
{
    int newmode;
    int sleep_fixed;
    int curstate;
    int sleep_current;

    // force an initial state change
    curmode = -2;

    // this is our "good enough" interval
    sleep_fixed = 10;

    while (1) {
        // look for blink mode changes
        newmode = getnewmode();
        if (newmode < 0)
            break;

        // got a mode change
        // force a change at the bottom
        if (curmode != newmode) {
            curstate = 0;
            curmode = newmode;
            blink_interval_remaining = 0;
        }

        // set up current sleep interval
        sleep_current = sleep_fixed;
        if (sleep_current > blink_interval_remaining)
            sleep_current = blink_interval_remaining;

        // do a sleep
        // NOTE: because the sleep is so short, we can use the simple msleep
        // this is the "good enough" way ...
        if (sleep_current > 0) {
            msleep(sleep_current);
            blink_interval_remaining -= sleep_current;
        }

        // flip the LED state at interval end
        if (blink_interval_remaining <= 0) {
            curstate = ! curstate;
            set_led_on(curstate);

            // set new interval
            if (curstate)
                blink_interval_remaining = blink_on_list[curmode];
            else
                blink_interval_remaining = blink_off_list[curmode];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Craig, 
1. Thanks for the response. I will try it out with the msleep_interruptible and post the result here    
2. Thanks for pointing to the possible race condition aswell. I will try with semaphores/mutexes and see  
3. As far as sending signals in kernel space, can we do that? i thought signals are only for userspace. Could you give me an example if that is not the case.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it's working for you. The solution was the minimal change from what you already had. I had thought about this a bit, and it should be possible to combine the monitor and blink threads into a single one, by doing a shorter sleep (e.g. 10ms--long enough to not hog resources but short enough so that it won't seem "sluggish"), polling for change, and resleep if no change and current blink interval not exhausted. But, then again, if it ain't broke, don't fix it ...

Comment: Craig, a large part of my earlier comment is some how lost. i have posted a question aswell. Anyways i will be asking the question again.
1. The msleep_interruptible was not wakeable using wake_up_process, but only with send_sig_info. I think msleep_interruptible is nothing but :
setstate(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE) and shedule() with delay, so i had expected wake_up_process to wakeup the thread sleeping with msleep_interruptible. Could you give me your feedback on that.

Comment: 2. As you said since it is working now , i am not going to change it. But neverthless it would be interesting to understand if it is possible to implement that in a single thread. Can you give me an example for that. 
My blink thread should set LED on for a second and depending on the mode it is in, has to set LED off after the 1 second for about 10 seconds  or 1 second. If we implement it in a single thread, polling will be delayed by those 10 seconds right?
Thanks

Comment: Cragi: I have updated the question. Please have a look at it.